# Iterate through data recovered from a table

Tags: javascript, loops, nested-loops

I've a data structure like this one:

```
map [ [ 'Polio',
    'Difterite',
    'Tetano',
    'Pertosse',
    'Epatite B',
    'Hib',
    'Morbillo',
    'Parotite',
    'Rosolia',
    'Varicella',
    'Meningococco C coniugato',
    'Pneumococco coniugato' ],
  [ 'Piemonte',
    'Valle D\'Aosta',
    'Lombardia',
    'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    'Prov Auton Trento',
    'Veneto',
    'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    'Liguria',
    'Emilia Romagna',
    'Toscana',
    'Umbria',
    'Marche',
    'Lazio',
    'Abruzzo',
    'Molise',
    'Campania',
    'Puglia',
    'Basilicata',
    'Calabria',
    'Sicilia',
    'Sardegna',
    'MEDIA NAZIONALE' ],
  [ '95,16',
    '94,90',
    '95,43',
    '94,87',
    '94,62',
    '93,80',
    '88,72',
    '88,72',
    '88,72',
    '0,85',
    '86,35',
    '91,32' ],
  [ '93,40',
    '92,92',
    '93,60',
    '92,82',
    '92,63',
    '92,63',
    '82,25',
    '82,15',
    '82,15',
    '0,39',
    '83,12',
    '88,46' ],
  [ '93,48',
    '93,37',
    '93,63',
    '93,38',
    '93,20',
    '92,95',
    '90,32',
    '90,21',
    '90,24',
    '0,83',
    '85,77',
    '86,77' ],
  [ '87,45',
    '87,49',
    '87,50',
    '87,45',
    '87,11',
    '87,17',
    '68,84',
    '68,80',
    '68,80',
    '4,16',
    '63,12',
    '81,67' ],
  [ '92,83',
    '92,66',
    '93,10',
    '92,52',
    '92,13',
    '91,95',
    '84,55',
    '84,38',
    '84,45',
    '3,04',
    '83,13',
    '87,34' ],
  [ '91,27',
    '91,29',
    '91,75',
    '91,26',
    '90,80',
    '90,62',
    '87,15',
    '87,05',
    '87,08',
    '84,03',
    '90,54',
    '84,64' ],
  [ '90,37',
    '90,28',
    '90,78',
    '90,22',
    '89,66',
    '89,59',
    '82,01',
    '81,85',
    '81,91',
    '66,95',
    '84,06',
    '81,02' ],
  [ '94,60',
    '94,50',
    '94,57',
    '94,49',
    '94,30',
    '93,92',
    '81,48',
    '81,32',
    '81,49',
    '10,57',
    '79,65',
    '92,80' ],
  [ '94,03',
    '93,75',
    '94,28',
    '93,63',
    '93,49',
    '92,93',
    '87,23',
    '87,00',
    '87,00',
    '0,90',
    '87,40',
    '91,53' ],
  [ '94,98',
    '94,95',
    '95,23',
    '94,96',
    '94,81',
    '94,57',
    '88,72',
    '88,67',
    '88,69',
    '78,21',
    '90,85',
    '92,94' ],
  [ '93,90',
    '93,78',
    '93,96',
    '93,71',
    '93,43',
    '93,65',
    '87,51',
    '87,46',
    '87,46',
    '0,52',
    '85,72',
    '90,32' ],
  [ '92,02',
    '91,75',
    '92,13',
    '91,74',
    '91,65',
    '91,52',
    '79,90',
    '79,87',
    '79,87',
    '2,75',
    '76,86',
    '88,04' ],
  [ '95,26',
    '95,24',
    '95,25',
    '95,21',
    '95,20',
    '95,20',
    '84,47',
    '84,46',
    '84,46',
    '6,51',
    '68,16',
    '91,85' ],
  [ '95,72',
    '95,71',
    '95,72',
    '95,71',
    '95,71',
    '95,71',
    '84,23',
    '84,23',
    '84,23',
    '4,91',
    '65,43',
    '86,34' ],
  [ '94,32',
    '94,32',
    '94,32',
    '94,32',
    '94,32',
    '94,32',
    '77,38',
    '77,38',
    '77,38',
    '47,68',
    '68,09',
    '92,63' ],
  [ '91,34',
    '91,34',
    '91,34',
    '91,34',
    '91,36',
    '91,49',
    '80,76',
    '80,76',
    '80,76',
    '9,15',
    '50,04',
    '82,96' ],
  [ '93,80',
    '93,81',
    '93,81',
    '93,81',
    '93,80',
    '93,73',
    '84,15',
    '84,15',
    '84,15',
    '81,82',
    '77,32',
    '92,54' ],
  [ '97,83',
    '97,83',
    '97,83',
    '97,83',
    '97,83',
    '97,83',
    '90,25',
    '90,25',
    '90,25',
    '76,95',
    '85,83',
    '97,08' ],
  [ '95,32',
    '95,32',
    '95,32',
    '95,32',
    '95,32',
    '95,24',
    '84,38',
    '84,38',
    '83,71',
    '53,02',
    '67,90',
    '88,65' ],
  [ '91,94',
    '91,92',
    '91,92',
    '91,92',
    '91,92',
    '91,91',
    '79,20',
    '79,18',
    '79,18',
    '75,36',
    '60,48',
    '89,37' ],
  [ '95,05',
    '95,05',
    '95,07',
    '95,05',
    '95,06',
    '95,05',
    '87,67',
    '87,67',
    '87,67',
    '67,15',
    '83,59',
    '94,14' ],
  [ '93,43',
    '93,35',
    '93,56',
    '93,33',
    '93,20',
    '93,03',
    '85,29',
    '85,23',
    '85,22',
    '30,73',
    '76,62',
    '88,73' ] ]
```

That is, an array for diseases, one for regions, and an array for each row of [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcqOh.png) values.

And I want transform these data in a json object like this:

```
json [ { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '93,40' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '93,48' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Autonoma Bolzano',
    coverage: '87,45' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Autonoma Trento',
    coverage: '92,83' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '91,27' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '90,37' },
  ...]
```

In fact, these data have been recovered from this pdf so the purpose is to reconstruct the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcqOh.png).

I know it's a simple thing, just create loops and iterate.

This is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < map[0].length; i++) {
    for(var j = 2; j < map.length; j++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < map[2].length; k++) {
            var year = 2015;
            var country = "Italy";
            var vaccine = map[0][i];
            var region = map[2][j];
            var coverage = map[j][k];

            // create this json object
            var thisJson = {year: year, country: country, vaccine: vaccine, region: region, coverage: coverage};

            // push this element to final json object
            json.push(thisJson);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
json [ { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    coverage: '95,16' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '94,90' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '94,90' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '94,90' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '94,90' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '94,90' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '94,90' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '94,90' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '94,90' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '94,90' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Valle D\'Aosta',
    coverage: '94,90' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '95,43' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '95,43' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '95,43' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '95,43' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '95,43' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '95,43' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '95,43' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '95,43' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '95,43' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Lombardia',
    coverage: '95,43' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    coverage: '94,87' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    coverage: '94,87' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    coverage: '94,87' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    coverage: '94,87' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    coverage: '94,87' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    coverage: '94,87' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    coverage: '94,87' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    coverage: '94,87' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    coverage: '94,87' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    coverage: '94,87' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Trento',
    coverage: '94,62' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Trento',
    coverage: '94,62' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Trento',
    coverage: '94,62' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Trento',
    coverage: '94,62' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Trento',
    coverage: '94,62' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Trento',
    coverage: '94,62' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Trento',
    coverage: '94,62' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Trento',
    coverage: '94,62' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Trento',
    coverage: '94,62' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Prov Auton Trento',
    coverage: '94,62' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '93,80' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '93,80' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '93,80' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '93,80' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '93,80' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '93,80' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '93,80' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '93,80' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '93,80' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Veneto',
    coverage: '93,80' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Liguria',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Liguria',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Liguria',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Liguria',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Liguria',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Liguria',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Liguria',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Liguria',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Liguria',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Liguria',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Emilia Romagna',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Emilia Romagna',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Emilia Romagna',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Emilia Romagna',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Emilia Romagna',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Emilia Romagna',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Emilia Romagna',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Emilia Romagna',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Emilia Romagna',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Emilia Romagna',
    coverage: '88,72' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Toscana',
    coverage: '0,85' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Toscana',
    coverage: '0,85' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Toscana',
    coverage: '0,85' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Toscana',
    coverage: '0,85' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Toscana',
    coverage: '0,85' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Toscana',
    coverage: '0,85' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Toscana',
    coverage: '0,85' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Toscana',
    coverage: '0,85' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Toscana',
    coverage: '0,85' },
  { year: 2015,
    country: 'Italy',
    vaccine: 'Polio',
    region: 'Toscana',
    coverage: '0,85' },
  ... 2540 more items ]
```

Obviously it doesn't work. There must be a problem with indices that I can't solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `shift` to remove the first element. And use `reduce` and `forEach` to iterate.

```
var diseases = data.shift(); /* Remove the first element and store it on variable */
var region = data.shift(); /* Remove the first element and store it on variable */
var year = 2015;
var country = 'Italy';

var result = data.reduce((c, v, i) => {
  v.forEach((o, k) => {
    c.push({year: year,country: country,vaccine: diseases[k],region: region[i],coverage: o});
  });
  return c;
}, []);
```

Here is a snippet

```js
var data = [
  ['Polio',
    'Difterite',
    'Tetano',
    'Pertosse',
    'Epatite B',
    'Hib',
    'Morbillo',
    'Parotite',
    'Rosolia',
    'Varicella',
    'Meningococco C coniugato',
    'Pneumococco coniugato'
  ],
  ['Piemonte',
    'Valle D\'Aosta',
    'Lombardia',
    'Prov Auton Bolzano',
    'Prov Auton Trento',
    'Veneto',
    'Friuli Venezia Giulia',
    'Liguria',
    'Emilia Romagna',
    'Toscana',
    'Umbria',
    'Marche',
    'Lazio',
    'Abruzzo',
    'Molise',
    'Campania',
    'Puglia',
    'Basilicata',
    'Calabria',
    'Sicilia',
    'Sardegna',
    'MEDIA NAZIONALE'
  ],
  ['95,16',
    '94,90',
    '95,43',
    '94,87',
    '94,62',
    '93,80',
    '88,72',
    '88,72',
    '88,72',
    '0,85',
    '86,35',
    '91,32'
  ],
  ['93,40',
    '92,92',
    '93,60',
    '92,82',
    '92,63',
    '92,63',
    '82,25',
    '82,15',
    '82,15',
    '0,39',
    '83,12',
    '88,46'
  ],
  ['93,48',
    '93,37',
    '93,63',
    '93,38',
    '93,20',
    '92,95',
    '90,32',
    '90,21',
    '90,24',
    '0,83',
    '85,77',
    '86,77'
  ],
  ['87,45',
    '87,49',
    '87,50',
    '87,45',
    '87,11',
    '87,17',
    '68,84',
    '68,80',
    '68,80',
    '4,16',
    '63,12',
    '81,67'
  ],
  ['92,83',
    '92,66',
    '93,10',
    '92,52',
    '92,13',
    '91,95',
    '84,55',
    '84,38',
    '84,45',
    '3,04',
    '83,13',
    '87,34'
  ],
  ['91,27',
    '91,29',
    '91,75',
    '91,26',
    '90,80',
    '90,62',
    '87,15',
    '87,05',
    '87,08',
    '84,03',
    '90,54',
    '84,64'
  ],
  ['90,37',
    '90,28',
    '90,78',
    '90,22',
    '89,66',
    '89,59',
    '82,01',
    '81,85',
    '81,91',
    '66,95',
    '84,06',
    '81,02'
  ],
  ['94,60',
    '94,50',
    '94,57',
    '94,49',
    '94,30',
    '93,92',
    '81,48',
    '81,32',
    '81,49',
    '10,57',
    '79,65',
    '92,80'
  ],
  ['94,03',
    '93,75',
    '94,28',
    '93,63',
    '93,49',
    '92,93',
    '87,23',
    '87,00',
    '87,00',
    '0,90',
    '87,40',
    '91,53'
  ],
  ['94,98',
    '94,95',
    '95,23',
    '94,96',
    '94,81',
    '94,57',
    '88,72',
    '88,67',
    '88,69',
    '78,21',
    '90,85',
    '92,94'
  ],
  ['93,90',
    '93,78',
    '93,96',
    '93,71',
    '93,43',
    '93,65',
    '87,51',
    '87,46',
    '87,46',
    '0,52',
    '85,72',
    '90,32'
  ],
  ['92,02',
    '91,75',
    '92,13',
    '91,74',
    '91,65',
    '91,52',
    '79,90',
    '79,87',
    '79,87',
    '2,75',
    '76,86',
    '88,04'
  ],
  ['95,26',
    '95,24',
    '95,25',
    '95,21',
    '95,20',
    '95,20',
    '84,47',
    '84,46',
    '84,46',
    '6,51',
    '68,16',
    '91,85'
  ],
  ['95,72',
    '95,71',
    '95,72',
    '95,71',
    '95,71',
    '95,71',
    '84,23',
    '84,23',
    '84,23',
    '4,91',
    '65,43',
    '86,34'
  ],
  ['94,32',
    '94,32',
    '94,32',
    '94,32',
    '94,32',
    '94,32',
    '77,38',
    '77,38',
    '77,38',
    '47,68',
    '68,09',
    '92,63'
  ],
  ['91,34',
    '91,34',
    '91,34',
    '91,34',
    '91,36',
    '91,49',
    '80,76',
    '80,76',
    '80,76',
    '9,15',
    '50,04',
    '82,96'
  ],
  ['93,80',
    '93,81',
    '93,81',
    '93,81',
    '93,80',
    '93,73',
    '84,15',
    '84,15',
    '84,15',
    '81,82',
    '77,32',
    '92,54'
  ],
  ['97,83',
    '97,83',
    '97,83',
    '97,83',
    '97,83',
    '97,83',
    '90,25',
    '90,25',
    '90,25',
    '76,95',
    '85,83',
    '97,08'
  ],
  ['95,32',
    '95,32',
    '95,32',
    '95,32',
    '95,32',
    '95,24',
    '84,38',
    '84,38',
    '83,71',
    '53,02',
    '67,90',
    '88,65'
  ],
  ['91,94',
    '91,92',
    '91,92',
    '91,92',
    '91,92',
    '91,91',
    '79,20',
    '79,18',
    '79,18',
    '75,36',
    '60,48',
    '89,37'
  ],
  ['95,05',
    '95,05',
    '95,07',
    '95,05',
    '95,06',
    '95,05',
    '87,67',
    '87,67',
    '87,67',
    '67,15',
    '83,59',
    '94,14'
  ],
  ['93,43',
    '93,35',
    '93,56',
    '93,33',
    '93,20',
    '93,03',
    '85,29',
    '85,23',
    '85,22',
    '30,73',
    '76,62',
    '88,73'
  ]
];

var diseases = data.shift(); /* Remove the first element */
var region = data.shift(); /* Remove the first element */
var year = 2015;
var country = 'Italy';

var result = data.reduce((c, v, i) => {
  v.forEach((o, k) => {
    c.push({year: year,country: country,vaccine: diseases[k],region: region[i],coverage: o});
  });
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```